# Custom Permalinks don't work on local LAMP installation

Tags: permalinks, local-installation

I'm on Ubuntu and using LAMP for local dev. I've several WordPress installations for different project and tried to set custom permalinks on all of them, but only default permalink setting ( `http://localhost/wpinstalation/?p=123` ) works, other settings are giving 404 error. Any idea how can I fix this?

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It sounds like you don't have rewrites turned on in your installation.

Find your httpd.conf file, find the following line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And remove the # at the beginning so it looks like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save and then restart the service.  Custom Permalinks should now work.  There might be an easier way but I'm not familiar with Linux

Comment: Thanks Manny but mod_rewrite wasn't installed. This answer solved my problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: oh, thanks!  I thought that other answer did the job for you, though.

Comment: yes, but from that answer I just got tips for mod_rewrite :)